# How to update a value inside an object with schema.findoneandupdate (Mongodb/mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot in discord.js and I want to make a database that keeps track of user messages, I've got the tracking part and the database structure down, which goes as follows:

```
_id: guildId,
metrics: {
  [userId]: 
  {
    messageCount: 1
  }
}
```

I'm using a mongoose schema, so how would I use schema.findoneandupdate to incrementally increase the messageCount value?

Comment: see the `$inc` update operator, mongodb documentation has examples. Also rethink your schema, you are saving data(userIds) in fields, its better to save them in an array of embeded documents fo example. For your update it works simple, but if you want to do other things you might have problems and you might need complicated things like  ObjectToArray and back to Object etc.

Comment: Please see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$inc` operator:

More detail:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/